# Bootstrap table using JSON loading empty values

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap table plugin and can't seem to get it to load any values into the table. I've used it before with success, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. The amount of rows is coming through, so I know the JSON data is being read by the bootstrap table, its just that the values are all empty in the table. I think the JSON is in the proper format, and the field names are all consistent. Any ideas?

Javacript

```
function populate_quote_table()
        {

            $('#quote_table').bootstrapTable({


                onSearch: function (text) {


                },

                onLoadSuccess: function (data) {

                    console.log(data);

                    //$('#test').html(data);

                },

                url: "<?php echo $site_url?>/quotes.php",
                striped: true,
                search: true,
                showRefresh:true,
                showColumns:true,
                pagination: true,
                showFilter: true,
                columns: [{
                    field: 'QID',
                    title: 'QID',
                }, {
                    field: 'CID',
                    title: 'Customer ID',
                }, {
                    field: 'Distance',
                    title: 'Distance',
                }]
            });
        };

    });
```

PHP

```
$i = 0;

    $quotes[] = array();

    if ($result) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $quotes[$i]['"QID"'] = $row['quote_id'];
            $quotes[$i]['"CID"'] = $row['customer_id'];
            $quotes[$i]['"Distance"'] = $row['distance']; 
            $i++;

        }
    }

    echo json_encode($quotes);
```

JSON Output

```
[
{
"QID": "1",
"CID": "1",
"Distance": "1"
},
{
"QID": "2",
"CID": "2",
"Distance": "11"
},
{
"QID": "3",
"CID": "20",
"Distance": "5"
},
{
"QID": "4",
"CID": "21",
"Distance": "67"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Extra quotes were not needed

Original - 
$quotes[$i]['"QID"'] = $row['quote_id'];

Working - 
$quotes[$i]['QID'] = $row['quote_id'];